# Python - Django persisting storage through gunicorn processes

Tags: python, django

I am having very specific use case of persisting storage inside Django production app, I cannot pickle instance of a class and save it to db, simple setup is needed of where instances of class can be saved to an array and accessed and  removed.

I want to look into `pymemcache` or would it be possible to persist memory inside file outside Django app?

I know this is more technical than programming, but any help is great. Thank you.

Comment: why cant you pickle it ... that is how you persist it ... (pymemcache will pickle it)... you don't have to pickle it necesarily ... but you do have to serialize it some how

Comment: it's selenium, any ideas how to serialize it?

Comment: why would you need to to pickle an instance of selenium?

Comment: How can I store object inside pymemcache without pickling it? or with any other library?

Comment: I am trying to reuse same selenium session, Remote selenium is popping Remote disconnected every time it loads